# Ember - Cannot create helper in test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-testing

I'm trying to create a helper for my test in order to simulate a model.

I'm receiving the follow error, though:

> : makeInventoryObjects is not defined

My test helper:

```
// ../tests/helpers/make-inventory-objects.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper('makeInventoryObjects', function() {
    const inventoryObjects = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}];
    return inventoryObjects;
});
```

My start-app in helpers contains `application.injectTestHelpers();`

The test which is failing:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
// I tried to import manually too and it did not work
// import makeInventoryObjects from '../../helpers/make-inventory-objects';

moduleForComponent('model-table', 'Integration | Component | model table', {
    integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
    this.set('inventoryResult', makeInventoryObjects());
    this.render(hbs`{{model-table inventoryResult}}`);
    assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), '');
});
```

Whenever I add the comment of the import, I get this error:

> : _frontendTestsHelpersMakeInventoryObjects["default"] is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason what I've done was failing is because I was trying to initialize the helper within the startApp and that is done only for `acceptance test`, not `integration test`.

I had to rewrite my helper to:

```
// ../tests/helpers/make-inventory-objects.js
export default function makeInventoryObjects() {
    const inventoryObjects = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'test'}];
    return inventoryObjects;
});
```

and then import in my test with the commented line.

Also, as a side note I missed to add in my `.jshintrc` my test helper **if I were doing acceptance test**. So, it was wrong for acceptance test as well.